# Camel filter doesn't work

Tags: filter, apache-camel, jsonpath

I have this Camel route:

```
 from("direct:myRoute")
      .id("myRoute")
      .setHeader("accept", constant("application/json"))
      .setHeader("Cache-Control", constant("no-cache"))
      .setHeader("content-Type", constant("application/json"))
      .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
      .setHeader("ID",constant("0072168580"))
      .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
      .removeHeader("CamelHttp*")
      .setBody(simple("${null}"))
      .streamCaching()
      .to("http4" + URL)
      .to("jolt:customerSpec.json?inputType=JsonString&outputType=JsonString&contentCache=true")
      .log("Before: ${body}")
      .filter()
      .jsonpath("$.[?(@.customerId == '${header.ID}')]")
      .log("After: ${body}");
```

The service I consume through http4 returns a response that is transformed with jolt, no problem so far. The JSON transformation result is:

```
[
  {
    "customerId": "0072168580",
    "documentId": "IDO"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072168580",
    "documentId": "ID2"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072168580",
    "documentId": "CDO"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072172460",
    "documentId": "IDO"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072172460",
    "documentId": "ID2"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072197658",
    "documentId": "IDO"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072197658",
    "documentId": "ID2"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "0072197658",
    "documentId": "CDO"
  }
]
```

The log after transformation shows:

```
INFO myRoute - Before: [{"customerId": "0072168580","documentId": "IDO"},{"customerId": "0072168580","documentId": "ID2"},{"customerId": "0072168580","documentId": "CDO"},{"customerId": "0072172460","documentId": "IDO"},{"customerId": "0072172460","documentId": "ID2"},{"customerId": "0072197658","documentId": "IDO"},{"customerId": "0072197658","documentId": "ID2"},{"customerId": "0072197658","documentId": "CDO"}]
```

Then, I want filter this response by customerId, I am setting a value in header to do it:

```
.jsonpath("$.[?(@.customerId == '${header.ID}')]")
```

Apparently, the jsonpath expression is ok, because the log shows me there were elements met the filtering criteria:

```
...
[main] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: @['customerId']
[main] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: @['customerId']
[main] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: @['customerId']
[main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor - Filter matches: true for exchange: Exchange[ID-XYZ-1529020843413-0-1]
```

However, the log after filtering shows me the same JSON, without filter it:

```
INFO myRoute - After: [{"customerId": "0072168580","documentId": "IDO"},{"customerId": "0072168580","documentId": "ID2"},{"customerId": "0072168580","documentId": "CDO"},{"customerId": "0072172460","documentId": "IDO"},{"customerId": "0072172460","documentId": "ID2"},{"customerId": "0072197658","documentId": "IDO"},{"customerId": "0072197658","documentId": "ID2"},{"customerId": "0072197658","documentId": "CDO"}]
```

I have been test the filter criteria in online tools, like http://jsonpath.com/ and it works:

[Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrnyV.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwMBz.png)

What could be wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the meaning of Filter EIP: it filters a message according to a predicate so, in your case, as the content of the exchange matches the *jsonpath* predicate, the message flew through the next step.

You have different way to achieve what you want, i.e

- by using the Split EIP and then filter out what you need
- by using the Message Translator EIP

Comment: Thanks a lot Luca !